# What is wrong in the inorder traversal in this code?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

Else condition is also running along with if condition in - inOrder(Node node) method

I actually add the node in BST using the given code and now I am trying to retrieve them using inorder traversal but output is not in inorder way as `Else` condition is executing after each `If`.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Node{
    int data; Node left; Node right;
    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        left = null;
        right = null;

    }
}
public class insert_tree {
    Node root;  
    public void addNode(int value) { 
        root = add(root, value);
    }
    private Node add(Node node, int value) {
        if(node == null) {
            node  = new Node(value);
            return node;
        }
         if(value == node.data) {
            node.left = add(node.left, value);
        }
        else if(value < node.data) {
            node.left = add(node.left, value);
        }       
        else {
            node.right = add(node.right, value);
        }
        
        return node;
    }

    private void inOrder(Node node) {
        if(node != null) {
            inOrder(node.left);
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            inOrder(node.right);
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("*" + " ");
        }
    }
    public void inorder() {
        inOrder(root);
    }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
        insert_tree obj = new insert_tree();
        obj.addNode(20);
        obj.addNode(14);
        obj.addNode(25);
        obj.addNode(10);
        obj.addNode(16);
        obj.addNode(25);
        obj.addNode(21);
        obj.addNode(30);
        //printing the tree
        obj.inorder();



    }
}
```

> Expected output should be :- 10 14 16 20 21 25 25 30
>
> Output I am getting:- * 10 * 14 * 16 * 20 * 21 * 25 * 25 * 30 *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void inOrder(Node node) {
    if (node != null) {
        if(node.left != null)
            inOrder(node.left);
        System.out.print(node.data + " ");
        if(node.right != null)
            inOrder(node.right);
    } else {
        System.out.print("*" + " ");
    }
}
```

I just added conditions to check if the node's neighbours aren't `null` before ordering them:

```
if(node.left != null)
if(node.right != null)
```

Output:

> 10 14 16 20 21 25 25 30